# How does one open a document in the native Google Drive iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

If I have a URL for a file in Google Drive, how does one open it in the native Google Drive app?

Basically trying to implement something similar to Open in Chrome (
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/ios-links )

Gmail on iOS already does this, so I'm trying to figure out what is the check to use for canOpenUrl and what to pass down to  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:... ];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warning: What you are trying to do is not officially supported by Google.  (For instance, they could change the url scheme at any time)

The Google Drive app's custom url scheme is

```
googledrive://
```

The "right" way to support interacting with Google Drive from your app is to use Google's provided SDK.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/quickstart-ios

Comment: I'm aware of the SDK, though my requirement is that I would like to open a file I already have the URL for from a separate native application, not read files from drive ( which is what the SDK focusses on ).

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is really old, but it comes up on the first page of a Google search for "ios open link in google drive". Besides, I had this question as well. Turns out the url scheme for Google Drive is googledrive:// (as Andy Obusek said in his answer.) To open a Google drive link in the Google drive app, just prefix the sharing url with the url scheme. For example, if I have a url to a Google doc (e.g. `http://link_to_google_doc`), I can have this automatically open in the Google drive app by prefixing with the url scheme (`googledrive://http://link_to_google_doc`). This worked for me. Keep in mind this is an unofficial answer.  I didn't read any documentation about this; I just played around with it until it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it can't open foreign document if in the link has my Google Apps domain, so remove it.

Too it seems Drive app can't open document if you have Docs app installed, so prepend http link with googledocs:// scheme.